# sql query to calculate a difference between cols in two different tables, grouped by common identifiers on the row

Tags: postgresql

This is probably an amazingly dumb question, but hopefully someone kind can help out while laughing :D
I'm doing this on postgres 9.5

I have two tables, all data types can int in this example
table1 has:

```
id     val

1      10

2      20

3      30
```

table2 has:

```
id     value

1      15

3      15

5      50
```

I would very much like a query that calculates the diff between the two tables (table2.val - table1.val) for each id, so that the result is:

```
id     diff

1      5

2      -20

3      -15

5      50
```

My difficulty is in figuring out how to do it when some ID's only exist in one table...

Please help :)

So to create my best attempt:

```
create table table1 (id int, value int);
create table table2 (id int, value int);
insert into table1 values 
(1,10),
(2,20),
(3,30);
insert into table2 values 
(1,15),
(3,15),
(5,50);


select table1.id, table2.value - table1.value as diff
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
group by table1.id, diff;
```

However this leads to :

```
id      diff
3       -15
1       5
```

If I try a full outer join I get:

```
select table1.id, table2.value - table1.value as diff
from table1
full outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.id
group by table1.id, diff;
```

which gives

```
id      diff
null    null
2       null
3       -15
1       5
```

Comment: Look at [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-table-expressions.html), and [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-conditional.html) (to handle the NULL values where a row only exists in one table).

Comment: Sounds good: but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do the outerjoin with coalesce: do you have some idea on how the query looks?

Comment: In questions like this, we do usually request that the asker post their attempt at the query, and let us know what problem they're seeing.

Comment: Updated the original post, hope this illustrates my difficulty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get results even if only one of the two tables has data, then you need `FULL JOIN`. The `COALESCE()` function can be used for the result when there are umatched rows (and you want the produced `NULL` to become `0` for example).

Assuming that `(id)` is `UNIQUE` in each table, I don't see why you think you need `GROUP BY` at all.

The query:

```
select
    coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
    coalesce(t2.value, 0) - coalesce(t1.value, 0) as diff
from table1 as t1
     full join table2 as t2
     on t1.id = t2.id ;
```

and slightly simpler, with `USING`:

```
select
    id,
    coalesce(t2.value, 0) - coalesce(t1.value, 0) as diff
from table1 as t1
     full join table2 as t2
     using (id) ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=559bfc287c9c5ddda977f54a1c30ce85)**.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks ypercube. Yep, the group by is a result of muddied thinking since the actual queries are much larger and complex, I was  trying to simplyfy them as much as possible. Thanks again!